# sequence of functions not converging to $f$ are contained in sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers

Given $f_{i}, f,(X, A) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}), i \in \mathbb{N}$ show that $$\{x \in X: f_{i}(x) \not\rightarrow f(x)\} \in A$$

Attempt:

We know that $f_{i}(x) \rightarrow f(x) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{i \to \infty}\inf f_{i}(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty}\sup f_{i}(x) = f(x)$. Now we recall that both the $\lim\inf$ and $\limsup$ are measurable and therefore $f(x)$ is measurable (if finite) and hence is contained in the sigma algebra.

Since a sigma algebra contains complements, our result follows.